# Remirror wysiwyg editor image uploadHandler usage

Tags: reactjs, prose-mirror, remirror

I have started using [Remirror](https://remirror.io) library for my much-needed WYSIWYG editor. There I am trying to upload the dropped images on the editor through [ImageExtension](https://remirror.io/docs/api/extension-image/). To do so I found in the [documentation](https://remirror.io/docs/api/extension-image/#property-uploadhandler) that there is a handler for it - `uploadHandler`

However, there, the mentioned types are not exported and hence it's becoming much difficult for me to get the required solution.

I particularly need help with a Remirror example that demonstrates how images are uploaded through the `uploadHandler()`